# С# datagridview база данных

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Есть таблица datagridview с данными. Нужно вывести только те строчки , у которых определенное имя.
Имя вводит пользователь .
1)Есть ли свойство , чтобы это реализовать ?
2) если использовать tableadapter как создать запрос с параметром? Могу создать запрос только на определенное имя .

Comment: Это так здесь не работает. Ответить на вопрос, как работать с сферической базой в вакууме неизвестного приложения используя те инструменты, которые вы не скажете, какие - в принципе невозможно. Добавьте в вопрос подробности о том, как вы пытались решить задачу, покажите код, расскажите что он делает, и что он должен делать, вот тогда будет шанс получить ответ.

Comment: 1) Есть, 2) Вот так: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240014/data-adapter-filter